# Perfectly good PHP/MySQL Login script not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Hey guys, I've been bashing my head around for hours now, over this login script. It's the one I always used, and I know it works on my version of MySQL. It just won't send me through to the correct authorized page, it will always redirect to the "login_failed.php" file.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost";
$username="*****"; 
$password="*****";
$db_name="*****"; 
$tbl_name="*****";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['user']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['pass'];

$encrypted_password=md5($mypassword);

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and passwd='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:main.php");
}
else {
header("location:login_failed.php");
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Have you ensured that a row actually does exist in the database?

Comment: If it's not working, then it can't be perfectly good.

Comment: And have you checked that there aren't *multiple* matching rows in the database?  You only check for `count == 1` not `count >= 1`.

Comment: And please, md5 **IS NOT** a form of encryption. `Hashing != Encryption`

Comment: Not only that, you `md5` the password, then you query with it plain text.  Completely defeating the point of the `md5` (And therein may lie your bug)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I see that is not quite right about the code:

1. Most likely you won't need `stripslashes()` since [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) has been deprecated.
2. You don't need to escape a hashed password. The result of an [`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) call can absolutely be trusted to be 32 hexadecimal characters.
3. Do NOT use `SELECT * ...` when you don't need all the fields.
4. You should probably [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the input (`$_POST['user']` and `$_POST['pass']`) to get rid of extra whitespaces that might've been accidentally inserted.
5. As ircmaxell pointed out, you are not using the hashed password on the query. I hope that was just a mistake in constructing the query.
6. You should salt your passwords. Read this article: [Just hashing is far from enough.](http://www.kavoir.com/2010/03/just-hashing-is-far-from-enough-how-to-position-against-dictionary-and-rainbow-attacks.html)

Now... Have you tried echoing the query and running it yourself to see what's actually going on? eg:

Remove the redirects and put an `echo $sql` before you call `mysql_query()`

Comment: Many thanks to all of you for bringing to light my many mistakes and shortcomings. Haven't spent much time with PHP, so I'm not 100% versed in the safest way to do this or the best way to do that. That is why I come to this place, because rather than just giving an answer, or point a problem, you (pretty much) all elaborate, which is great for learning.

Answer (score 2):

there might be *two* such users in the db... also, check if the values you use in the query are correct. do you use any non-latin/special characters in username/password?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but with just quickly looking at your code you are encrypting the password, but then not using that in the query.  try...

```
//instead of ...
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and passwd='$mypassword'";

//try...        
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and passwd='$encrypted_password'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are checking for error after the call to mysql_query like this, for example:

```
if (!($res = mysql_query($query)))
  die("MySQL query $query failed: ".mysql_error()) ;
```

If that does not error out for you, add:

```
echo("Running query $query");
```

prior to the call to mysql_query() and see if the query is what you expected it to be, and if yes, if it will run successfully from the MySQL command line client or some other tool that allows running of queries against MySQL.